# Unwanted result web scrapping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrap data from the page which get opens by clicking these quest no-8526724 of the table but the click is not working quest no is getting printed

enter code here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

## Open the website in the browser

driver.get('https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787')

## Wait for the table to load

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'table_id')))

## Find all the quest numbers in the table

quest_numbers = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table//tbody//tr//td[2]')

## Click on each quest number and print the resulting page

for quest_number in quest_numbers:
quest_number_text = quest_number.text
print(quest_number_text)
current_url = driver.current_url
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", quest_number)

```
WebDriverWait(driver,40).
until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'posting-second- 
header'))) 
page_source = driver.page_source
print('Quest Number:', quest_number_text)
print('Page Source:', page_source)
time.sleep(2) 
# Go back to the table
driver.back()
```

## Close the browser

driver.quit()

Comment: Searching the HTML on that page, there are 4 tables. I would imagine you are after is the table with an id of `table_id` and has the classes of `datatable table table-striped table-bordered  dataTable no-footer`.

Answer (score 1):

Data in that table is dynamic, and is hydrated from another api endpoint. Here is one way of obtaining that data, by scraping that endpoint directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r = s.get('https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/browse_posting/?search_id=&postings_since_last_login=&draw=1&columns[0][data]=render_my_posting&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=false&columns[0][orderable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=render_post_date&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=false&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=render_project_id&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=render_category_search_string&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[3][orderable]=true&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=render_name&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[4][orderable]=true&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[5][data]=bid_date_str&columns[5][name]=&columns[5][searchable]=true&columns[5][orderable]=true&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[6][data]=render_city&columns[6][name]=&columns[6][searchable]=true&columns[6][orderable]=true&columns[6][search][value]=&columns[6][search][regex]=false&columns[7][data]=render_county&columns[7][name]=&columns[7][searchable]=true&columns[7][orderable]=true&columns[7][search][value]=&columns[7][search][regex]=false&columns[8][data]=state_code&columns[8][name]=&columns[8][searchable]=true&columns[8][orderable]=true&columns[8][search][value]=&columns[8][search][regex]=false&columns[9][data]=render_owner&columns[9][name]=&columns[9][searchable]=true&columns[9][orderable]=true&columns[9][search][value]=&columns[9][search][regex]=false&columns[10][data]=render_solicitor&columns[10][name]=&columns[10][searchable]=true&columns[10][orderable]=true&columns[10][search][value]=&columns[10][search][regex]=false&columns[11][data]=posting_type&columns[11][name]=&columns[11][searchable]=true&columns[11][orderable]=true&columns[11][search][value]=&columns[11][search][regex]=false&columns[12][data]=render_empty&columns[12][name]=&columns[12][searchable]=true&columns[12][orderable]=true&columns[12][search][value]=&columns[12][search][regex]=false&columns[13][data]=render_empty&columns[13][name]=&columns[13][searchable]=true&columns[13][orderable]=true&columns[13][search][value]=&columns[13][search][regex]=false&columns[14][data]=render_empty&columns[14][name]=&columns[14][searchable]=true&columns[14][orderable]=true&columns[14][search][value]=&columns[14][search][regex]=false&columns[15][data]=render_empty&columns[15][name]=&columns[15][searchable]=true&columns[15][orderable]=true&columns[15][search][value]=&columns[15][search][regex]=false&columns[16][data]=project_id&columns[16][name]=&columns[16][searchable]=true&columns[16][orderable]=true&columns[16][search][value]=&columns[16][search][regex]=false&start=0&length=25&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1685987743241')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].replace(r'<[^<>]*>', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    DT_RowId    render_my_posting   render_post_date    render_project_id   render_category_search_string   render_name     bid_date_str    render_city     render_county   state_code  render_owner    render_solicitor    posting_type    render_empty    project_id
0   0       05/12/2023  8526724     Street/Roadway Reconstruction   Key No. 22408 3000 E & FOOTHILL RD CURVE, TWI...    06/06/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Twin Falls  ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8526724
1   1       05/16/2023  8529878     Traffic Control Devices (Signa...   Key No. 24192 SH-75, Ohio Gulch Road Intersec...    06/06/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Blaine  ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8529878
2   2       05/18/2023  8534098     Roadway Pavement Markings   Key No. 23815 FY24 D6 STRIPING  06/06/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Bonneville, Fremont,...     ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8534098
3   3       05/19/2023  8536176     Roadway Pavement Markings   Key No. 21842, I-84, FY23 D4 Interstate Striping    06/06/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Various     ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8536176
4   4       05/22/2023  8539402     Seal Coating    Key No. 20592 / 20482 SH-3, CDA RV BR to I-90...    06/06/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Kootenai    ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8539402
5   5       05/22/2023  8539418     Bridges/Overpasses  Key No. 23474 US-20; EXIT 343 INTERCHANGE   06/13/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Fremont     ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8539418
6   6       05/25/2023  8544737     Pavement - Marking  Key No. 23791, FY24 D1 STRIPING     06/13/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Kootenai and Shoshon...     ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8544737
7   7       05/25/2023  8544742     Bridge (Replacement or Rehabil...   Key No. 20487 FY24 D1 BRIDGE REPAIR     06/13/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Kootenai and Shoshon...     ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8544742
8   8       06/05/2023  8554006     Street/Roadway Reconstruction   Key No. 24249 SH-11 PIERCE TO GRANGEMONT ROAD...    06/27/2023 02:00 PM MDT     N/A     Clearwater  ID  Idaho Transportation...     Idaho Transportati...   Construction Project        8554006
```

Comment: See Here I want to scrap data from the page which get open by clicking these quest no-8526724 of the table

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed: change your quotes. I ran you script and it works.

The line:

```
# URL of the website to scrape
url = ´https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787´
```

Must be:

```
# URL of the website to scrape
url = "https://qcpi.questcdn.com/cdn/posting/?group=1950787&provider=1950787"
```

The output I got:

```
[<tr>
<th class="">Saved Search</th>
<th class="sorting" id="id_searchptbl_th1" onclick="sortTable(1)">Name</th>
<th class="sorting" id="id_searchptbl_th2" onclick="sortTable(2)">Search Criteria</th>
<th class="sorting" id="id_searchptbl_th3" onclick="sortTable(3)">Days Notified</th>
<th class="sorting" id="id_searchptbl_th4" onclick="sortTable(4)">Default</th>
<th class="">Delete</th>
</tr>]
```